# gridview not displaying all rows in landscape android

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview, landscape

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar_bg_orange"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/selectedDayMonthYear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_top_header"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/prevMonth"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar_left_arrow_selector"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/currentMonth"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:background="@drawable/calendar_bar"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/nextMonth"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar_right_arrow_selector"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/calendarheader"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/blue_bg_with_text"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/calendar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="100px"
                android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:numColumns="@integer/grid_rows"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/getAttendance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="Attendance"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my getView() from Adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.day_gridcell, parent, false);
        }
```

In portrait mode the display is fine like this:

[image]

In landscape mode shows only 1 row

[image]

I have tried putting column specification in integers.xml in the res folder without any success. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

One reason I can see is your button's width is `wrap_content` which will leave some space around in `landscape` mode and similar issues.

You probably need to create specific layout for landscape view. check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html).

This will give you extra legroom to customize you layout as per your screen size.

Comment: Can you suggest how should the landscape layout be different from the portrait layout shown above. Thanks

Comment: Depends on how you want to design for example if you want `select` button to grab full width make it match_parent with recommended margin (16dp).